# Basic example of $\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I need some practice finding the $\sigma$-algebra generted by a radnom variable, but I can't find any worked examples online. I was wondering if anyone could work through the solution to the following example I've made up:

Let $X : ([0,1],\mathbb{P}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B})$, where $\mathbb{P} = \lambda$ is the lebesgue measure  ($\lambda[a,b] = b-a$) and $\mathscr{B}$ is the Borel sigma algebra. 
Define: 
$$X(\omega) = 
\begin{cases}
0 &x <1/3\\
1 & x \in [1/3, 2/3]\\
2x & x \in (2/3, 1]\\
\end{cases}
$$

Intuitively, I think it might be something like 
$$\sigma(X) = \{X^{-1}(B): B \in \mathscr{B}\} = \sigma(\{[0,1/3),[1/3,2/3],\mathscr{B}((2/3,1]),[0,1]\})$$
Am I right, and how do I make this rigorous? If anyone could point me to more worked examples that would also be good. 
Thanks!

Comment: A nice alternative is to show that $\{\omega: X(\omega)\leq y\}$ is contained your sigma algebra for all $y$. Such intervals generate the borel sigma algebra.